# How does referencing document. work within a React Component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When you reference document.something, for example: document.addEventListener() within a React Component, does that event listener get applied only to the html that is rendered by the react component or to the entire page html?

Answer (score 1):

Entire page html. if you use the traditional DOM api, react does not scope or effect it any differently

Comment: To add to this answer, if you want to add things directly through React and not touch the DOM, you need to use React refs, which are basically references to React elements in the virtual DOM that React creates.